# Image not visible in list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list view with image and text.Now whenever i open the list view initially the image is visible.Now when i scroll the list the images are being visible.Also i have put condition on which image should be displayed when,but in beginning all the images are same the images are only changed when i scroll the list.I know this issue is related to recycle of the list but i am not able to solve it.Please do help me

Code

```
public class ShareWithMeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SharedWithMeModel> data;

    public ShareWithMeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SharedWithMeModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.share_with_me_custom_list, viewGroup, false);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sharedwithme_title);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sharedwithme_name);
            holder.tvSharedOn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sharedwithme_on);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_sharedwithme_image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.tvTitle.setText(data.get(i).getTitle());
        if (data.get(i).getName().equals("")) {
            holder.tvName.setText("Shared With " + data.get(i).getName());
        } else {
            holder.tvName.setText("Shared With " + data.get(i).getName());
        }
        holder.tvSharedOn.setText(data.get(i).getDate());

        if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".jpg") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".png") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".jpeg") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".gif") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".tiff")) {
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
        }

        if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".docx") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".doc")) {
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.docx);
        }

        if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".xls") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".xlxs")) {
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.excel);
        }

        if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".pdf")) {
            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pdf);
        }

//        if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".ppt")) {
//            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.);
//        }


        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle, tvName, tvSharedOn;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add snapshot of your listview ?

Comment: data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".jpg")  check this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class ShareWithMeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SharedWithMeModel> data;

    public ShareWithMeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SharedWithMeModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.share_with_me_custom_list, null);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sharedwithme_title);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sharedwithme_name);
            holder.tvSharedOn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sharedwithme_on);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_sharedwithme_image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        holder.tvTitle.setText(data.get(i).getTitle());
        if (data.get(i).getName().equals("")) {
            holder.tvName.setText("Shared With " + data.get(i).getName());
        } else {
            holder.tvName.setText("Shared With " + data.get(i).getName());
        }
        holder.tvSharedOn.setText(data.get(i).getDate());

        if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".jpg") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".png") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".jpeg") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".gif") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".tiff")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        }else if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".docx") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".doc")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.docx);
        }else if (data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".xls") || data.get(i).getExtension().equals(".xlxs")) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.excel);
        }else{
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvSharedOn;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , hope it might helpfull

replace all

```
holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.filename);
```

with

```
holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.filename);
```

or change these methods

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```